# python `codecs.open` with `utf8` encoding is very slow when reading long lines

Tags: python, utf-8, codec

Reading a file with `codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf8')` is very slow for a file with long lines. Is this behavior expected? Or am I doing something wrong?

Below is a short test code where I read a file `./data/longfile` first with just `open` and then with `codecs.open('r', 'utf8')` the time difference is very large!

```
import time
vf = './data/longfile'
st = time.time()
with open(vf, 'r') as vfile:
    for line_vf in vfile:
        print len(line_vf),
print 'done'
print 'time:', time.time() - st

import codecs
st = time.time()
with codecs.open(vf, 'r', 'utf8') as vfile:
    for line_vf in vfile:
        print len(line_vf),
print 'done'
print 'time with codecs-utf8:', time.time() - st
```

Output:

```
130013 1667401 33266 done #num chars per line
time: 0.00615406036377 #fast
130013 1667401 33266 done #num chars per line
time with codecs-utf8: 0.418385028839 #---> 70X slower!!
```

Comment: Searching for "python codecs open slow" got this link rather quickly https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/python-file-reading-benchmarks/ seems like this was benchmarked already.

Comment: You should also compare to `io.open(vf, 'r', encoding='utf8')`.